# rxjs, what's the difference about observer.next() and observer.onNext()?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

What's the difference between `observer.next()` and `observer.onNext()` in RxJs? Is one version 4 and the other 5?

What about `observer.complete()` and `observer.onCompleted()`?

I'm just starting out with RxJS and looking for RxJS v4 docs.

Is [this the website](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) for v4 or v5 documentation?

Comment: What is the question exactly? The v5 API is different from the v4 API, yes. You can find the v4 API on GitHub: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/v4.1.0/doc

Comment: @Whymarrh Because, when I call `observer.complete`, it throw an error. Thanks for the v4 doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the same. See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#observer-interface-changes-also-subjects.

Website http://reactivex.io/rxjs/ is automatically generated from RxJS 5 docblocks.

RxJS 4 is mostly covered here http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html (that covers also other Rx variants).